# .NET / C# - Proper Method to Use Here - LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, loops

I'm a total newb to LINQ.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class Folder
{
    public Folder(string path)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        IList<FileInfo> fis = new List<FileInfo>();
        files.SomeMethod(x => fis.Add(new FileInfo(x)));
    }

}
```

What is the correct method name to replace SomeMethod with this to get it to work?
I'd basically just like a more concise way of writing a loop here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

sounds like you're looking for something like the ForEach function in List.  You could do the following...

```
files.ToList().ForEach(x => fis.Add(new FileInfo(x)));
```

or you could do something like this as a more direct approach

```
IList<FileInfo> fis = (from f in Directory.GetFiles(path)
                      select new FileInfo(f)).ToList();
```

or...

```
IList<FileInfo> fis = Directory.GetFiles(path).Select(s => new FileInfo(s)).ToList();
// or 
IList<FileInfo> fis = Directory.GetFiles(path)
                      .Select(s => new FileInfo(s))
                      .ToList();
```

Or - without using any linq at all, how about this one?...

```
IList<FileInfo> fis = new List<FileInfo>(new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles());
```

Answer (score 4):

You *could* use the static ForEach method:

```
Array.ForEach(x => fis.Add(new FileInfo(x)));
```

However, you can easily replace the entire function with this one line:

```
IList<FileInfo> fis = Directory.GetFiles(path).
    Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var fis =
    new List<FileInfo>(
        from f in Directory.GetFiles(path) select new FileInfo(f));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's already a DirectoryInfo method to do this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] fis = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
```

If you need it to be a List, use Enumerable.ToList.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
IList<FileInfo> fis = new List<FileInfo>();
Array.ForEach(files, x => fis.Add(new FileInfo(x)));
```